# Abrir Genexus desde C#

Tags: c#, genexus, extensiones

Necesito abrir una kb desde `c#` y lo que encontré en la web no está funcionado.

El código que me falla

```
  ExceptionManager.ConfigurationFile = configurationFile;
            CacheManager.ConfigurationFile = configurationFile;
            if(!nostart)
                Artech.Core.Connector.CustomStartBL(path, packagesPath, false);
            nostart = true;
 kb = KnowledgeBase.Open(location);
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Se solucionó al volver a instalar gx y el sdk